# Cannot submit the data to another page using jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>jQuery Mobile loadPage() Method</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="content_container">
            <form id="my_form">
                <input type="text" id="name" />
                <input type="text"  id="surname"/>
                <input type="button" id="yes">

            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var storePageLoaded = false;

        $(document).on('click', '#yes', function() {
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "searchresult.php",
              data: $("form#my_form").serialize(),
              success: function(data){            
              $.each(data, function(i, elem) {

            nic_list.push({label: elem['p_nic']});
        });
              }
            }).done(function (data) {
             $.mobile.changePage('next-page.html',{transition:"slide"});
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert(error);
         });
       return false;
      });
    </script>
```

I created this page to send some form data to php file and  print the data in a another page.But when i try this i get following error .I have change the code little bit to retrieve the data .It works fine but i need to populate the data next-page.html

```
  10-14 11:10:05.108: E/Web Console(9066): Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'jqmData' at http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js:2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '#yes', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "searchresult.php",
    data: $("form#my_form").serialize(),
    success: function(response){            
           alert(success);
    }
  }).done(function (data) {
      $.mobile.changePage('next-page.html',{transition:"slide"});
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert(error);
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: thank u for your help i need to know why my code isn't working and how to show submit data in next page.html

Comment: Enrich your answer with some explanation.

Comment: I change the  Ved answer.I  can Take the data retrieve from my php file but i need to populate that data on the next-page.html.Can you elp me to do this

Comment: @LahiruPrasanna: Don't edit like that. Add a comment, or modify your question.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake